# UltraVNC cannot control the screen, but macOS Screen Sharing can

Tags: vnc, vncserver, kaspersky, ultravnc

Environment:
**Server:** Windows 10 Pro (x64) PC running UltraVNC Server 1.2.2.3 and Kaspersky Internet Security 19.0.0.1088(d).
**Clients:** macOS 10.13.6 connecting via (built-in) Screen Sharing; W10 Pro (x64) connecting via UltraVNC Viewer 1.2.2.3.

I am able to successfully connect to my server PC in macOS (VNC protocol) and do the standard screen sharing/control thing. I have never had any issues here.

However, when I try to connect to the server PC from another W10 PC, using UltraVNC Viewer, I can successfully connect and view the server PC, but I cannot control it. I have tried explicitly white-listing uvnc apps in KIS, turning off KIS on the server, and even installed RealVNC viewer, but I get the same results - not able to control the server PC. All computers are on my home LAN, 192.168.0.x address. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally figured it out - total n00b mistake - I had the regular VNC password saved in my macOS keychain, but was typing in the View-Only password to the other VNC instances, when I thought it was the regular password. Now that I have all the passwords sorted out, all is working again.